# how to hide .php extension from url?

Tags: .htaccess

I am New in Php Development. Any error in the following code..

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Its not working in my web site.

Comment: no errors in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

and put your htaccess file in the parent directory.